# If I press cancel on confirmation box, it closes page which I don't want happening

Tags: javascript, confirm

i have an confirmation box where user can select OK to continue or Cancel to close box and stay on same page. Problem is that in all browsers except for Opera if I click cancel in the confirmation box, then the box closes and the user stays on the same page which is fine, but in Opera if I click on cancel it would close the page as well.

What do I need to include so that in Opera if I click cancel in the confirmation box, it would close the box but does not close the page?

below is code:

```
               function showConfirm(){

             var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

             if (confirmMsg==true)
             {
             submitform();   
             }else{
             parent.close();      

}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the parent.close? I don't think you want that there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the `else` block is unneeded as the parent of an element can be `window`. That's why the page is closed.

I'm not sure what did you want to close with that `parent.close()`

```
function showConfirm(){
    var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

    if (confirmMsg)
    {
        submitform();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I used w3schools example and it had a parent.close() so I thought this was needed with the cancel button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clicking cancel on the confirm box should close your confirmation window anyway, which is what I presume you want to do

http://jsfiddle.net/kRqCd/2/

Comment: Hi, thanks I used w3schools example and it had a parent.close() so I thought this was needed with the cancel button. Thanks